# Cant seem to fit image so that its relative to device screen size

Tags: html, css, image, resize, position

I am currently in the middle of a bootcamp and I might just be trying to jump the gun here but I went about building my personal site on my own while following my instructor and my design has led me to an issue she may have simply not covered yet. I have an image across the top on my top-container which will not fit to screen, relative to the device. help!! See here https://milkypawz.github.io/hired/

Answer (score 0):

guess what guys, figured that ish out on my own! Had to make another container and throw those in a column, the set object-fit to contain. YES BABY!! This trial and error built into coding.. i live for it.